# Artifactory Continuous integration approach

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

So far, I have artifactory hooked up to jenkins such that jenkins is pushing up artifacts to artifactory on every push to master. I doubt I'll be able to influence the other devs to alter their behavior and it seems like pushing artifacts to artifactory in this manner is a waste. Enter build retention, which seems like a nice solution.

So what I'm looking for is some advice on the best course of action here. Googling for this hasn't been fruitful.

It seems like a good idea to have, say retention for up to the last 20 or so builds. The artifacts from these builds will be candidates subject to further testing and usage. Then should one be chosen as a release candidate, to be included as part of some superset release package, it seems logical that I would want to ensure that the selected build is retained indefinitely in the interests of traceability and reproducibility. If I did this, all of the interim or otherwise ignored candidate builds would then disappear as part of a retention policy.

Is this a sensible strategy? If so, how would one execute it? I understand how to deploy and set retention policies as per artifactory's [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins) but not about the prospect of "unsetting" it on blessed builds. I have read that build promotion can be employed to a achieve something like this but in the context of promotion it seems to imply copying to another repository which isn't necessarily what I am after. (Though I am open to guidance on best practice in this regard.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> not about the prospect of "unsetting" it on blessed builds.

That is where the [notions of snapshots and releases comes in handy](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories).

Simply push to two different Artifactory local repositories, each with their own retention policy:

- 20 days for the snapshots one (where you can override the same version over and over, with artifactory keeping timestamps revisions of that version artifact)
  Set also `Max Unique Snapshots` to 20.
- 0 days (infinite retention) for blessed artifacts that will go into production.

Comment: Does it need to be a different repository or will a copy to a different path within the same repo work? I have no admin access in artifactory so I'll be relying on the jenkins artifactory plugin for control of retention policies over specific builds.

Comment: @GregoryKuhn You could manage both snoashots and release in the same Artifactory repo, provided it was configured to handle releases.